# Rotate video preserving as close as possible quality to original

Tags: video, video-editing, rotate

I'm trying to rotate a video preserving encapsulation, codec, metadata and as close as possible quality, bitrate, filesize etc. Although this seems to be a common problem, I didn't seem to find all day one universal solution of it that will suit me.

I have a number of video files in various formats (filetype, codec) that need to be rotated 90, 180 or 270 degrees.

I've learned that it should be done via reencoding them and there are many apps that do so, but they typically also change codecs, filetype etc.

Closest to my needs seems to be avconv using "transpose" filter but it doesn't seem to preserve metadata and moreover, the quality seems to deteriorate. Additionally, in MJPEG encoded files there are problems with colors in the output file.

Does anybody know the proper syntax for avconv to perform described task or know any other tool that does so?

Comment: Which OS must it run on, and what is your price limit?

Comment: This Q is better suited at [Video Production](http://video.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Preferably it's Mac and free. But all the other solutions are welcome.